# OOB Search core result webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, fast-for-sharepoint

This might be very simple, but since I am new to Sharepoint, I could not find enough information that helped me to understand how to implement OOB Search core result webpart.

What I understand is, Sharepoint is using search core result to display all the search results and we can change the outlook, such as title or so, by modying xslt . And also we can use keyword to filter the result. But to understand the concept, I try to create my own search webpart,  by adding new  search core result webpart available in Sharepoint 2010 (Standard edition). And now I want my newly added search core result to diplay information from my one of the existing list that I have created. But I could not find a way to map newly added Search core result webpart to the list. Also I could not see any default xslt.

When I google, I find lot of information concerning changing the look of search webparts but could not find information that explains about creating and mapping using OOB search web part. Can anybody suggest me link, where I can get basic steps to understand Search core result webpart and its mapping.

Thankyou..

Answer (score 5):

You would maybe need to understand how search works prior to developing your own in the 1st place - a fast track video, check here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJIhgL2zRwI. Also there quite a lot of videos on TechNet around search for developers.

So, for your case you would need a Search scope (it could be a site collection level) which targets either your list - using a Rule in the Search scope to restrict its location only at list/library (http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/) or better, you should use a Content Type as you could expose "search managed properties" useful in advanced search scenarios (example here http://sharepoint.licomputersource.com/2010/11/configure-custom-search-scope-in-sharepoint-2010-to-rollup-tasks-documents-or-sites-from-anywhere-part-1/ or http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2007/03/23/site-directory-in-moss-2007-via-a-custom-search-scope.aspx)

Simplified even more, basically you need to configure the web part to show only results from that particular scope (using the Scope property). This article gives a full example, from configuration, to search core results web parts, refinement panel, etc. http://avisuj.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/building-search-driven-applications-in-sharepoint-crawl-walk-run/

As a 2nd step you need to choose and expose properties you would like to be shown http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-customize-search-results-in-sharepoint-2010/

So again, you don't really need to develop your own at this stage, as it is all done via customizations.

Answer (score 0):

To map search core result webpart to a particular list you have to make use of search scope
for details you can follow:
http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/